# Loop para receber dados de formulário e gravar com array

Tags: php

Estou querendo receber os dados do formulário com loop, eu localizei um exemplo assim:

```
foreach($_POST as $nome_campo => $valor) {
   $comando = "$" . $nome_campo . "='" . $valor . "';";
   eval($comando);
}
```

Porém eu não sei como posso fazer para gravar ou editar esses dados no banco.
Não sei se é possível, pois essa variável `$comando` não me mostra nada fora do `foreach`.

Quero pegar:
Nome, email, senha, obs via _POST do formulário e adicionar no banco usando um loop, para não precisar fazer:
`$nome = $_POST['nome'];`
`$email = $_POST['email']`...

e mandar gravar esses dados no banco.

Comment: Por que está usando o `eval`?

Comment: Esse código aí, além de não ser seguro, utilizando o `eval` em dados vindo do usuário, poderia ser substituído apenas pela função [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php): `extract($_POST)`. E que banco de dados está utilizando? Você já conseguiu conectá-lo? Qual é a estrutura da tabela?

Comment: Então eu quero fazer o recebimento de dados com loop e gravar no banco mysql e conseguir esse codigo ai pesquisando por isso no google.

Não sei como fazê-lo, mais preciso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar criar um array antes do loop e inserir nele o valor das variaveis do `$_POST` assim :

```
$data = array();
foreach($_POST as $nome_campo => $valor) {
   $data[$nome_campo] = $valor;
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) values (";

foreach($data as $id => $value) {
    $sql = $sql . " " . $value . " ,";
}

// removo a "," do ultimo loop
$sql = trim(trim($sql),',');
$sql = $sql . ")" ;
```

Mas esse codigo pode mudar dependendo das regras do seu banco, por exemplo se o campo puder ser null poderia criar um `if` ou `switch` dentro do `foreach`, cabe você especificar mais a perguntar ou melhorar esse codigo.

Eu só criei a variavel $data pq pelo que eu entendi vc qria criar uma variavel para receber os valores da variavel `$_POST` mas poderia cortar a primeira parte do meu codigo e ir direto assim :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) values (";

foreach($_POST as $id => $value) {
    $sql = $sql . " " . $value . " ,";
}

// removo a "," do ultimo loop
$sql = trim(trim($sql),',');
$sql = $sql . ")" ;
```

Vale lembrar que esse codigo esta vulneravel a injection, então fazer um tratamento para evitar isso seria bom.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.
ajudou demais.